# How to change FiveStar style in a view?

Tags: views, rating

I changed my Five Star style in a content type to Minimal, but when I add that field in a view it shows in Default style (stars) and as you may guess I want it to display in Minimal style here too.
How can I change its style now? (I'm using Drupal 7.1)
Thanks.